# preg_replace syntax to add chrs after the closing of an image tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a preg_replace syntax to add something (anything) after the /> of an image tag that is within a string I have.

So for example

```
$string="here is a <img src="images/test.gif" /> string!"
```

needs to become...

```
$string="here is a <img src="images/test.gif" /><br> string!"
```

Comment: did you forget to escape the " in the string?

Comment: How predictable is the format of the image tag?  Will it always have a src attribute and no other attributes?  Will it always be closed with `/>` and not simply `>` or even `></img>` (which might not even be valid but whatever).

Comment: Why don't you do that with CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = '<img src="test" />';
$result = preg_replace('/(<img[^>]+>(?:<\/img>)?)/i', '$1<br />', $string);
```

This will match

```
<img />
<img>
<img></img>
```

as well as any uppercase variations.

A breakdown of the expression:

- Outer parentheses - match the regular expression and capture into
  backreference 1
- Match the characters `<img` literally
- Match any character which is not `>` between 1 and unlimited times as many times as possible
- Match the character `>` literally (to account for stopping above when it was found)
- Match `</img>` literally between zero and 1 times (optional because of the ?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string = 'here is a <img src="images/test.gif" /> string!';
$string_to_insert = '<br>';

$pattern = '/(.*?\/>)(.*)/';
$replacement = '${1}' . $string_to_insert . '${2}';
$new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Output:

```
here is a <img src="images/test.gif" /><br> string!
```

Explanation:

1. Catches all characters until, and included, `/>` is reached and stores it in group 1, `$1`
2. Catches the rest of the characters and stores them in group 2, `$2`
3. Finally makes adds the two parts on each side of the string to be inserted.

Note that this regex will only work if:

- There's no other tags closing with `/>` in the string
- It is properly closed with `/>` and no other way like `></img>` or not closed at all `>`